# How can the power saving feature on Android phones be set not to kill tracking apps?

Tags: battery-life, gps-tracking, task-management

Those who choose a simpler cyclometer consisting of only a speedometer and distance display, but that does not include a GPS tracker can use their Android smartphone quite nicely with one of many tracker apps. At the limit a smartphone + suitable mount can act as a cyclometer.

If you leave one such app, Strava, running on iOS/iPhone, "out-of-the-box" and without any special adjustments iOS will not kill the app, despite that it uses an unusual amount of power for the GPS sensor.

But some Android phones, in particular Samsung Galaxy phones, reportedly kill Strava after a few minutes, which precludes tracking rides.

How can the power saving feature on Android phones—specifically on Samsung Galaxy phones—be set not to kill tracking apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link-only answers are frowned upon (for good reason) on Stack Exchange sites, but for every rule, there may be exceptions.

And when there is a long-standing canonical site with all the answers you likely need, I think that's going to be a good exception.

Samsung devices are ***notorious*** for aggressively killing apps when they really should not.  Some speculate they do this to make it look like their devices have longer battery life than they actually do.

To delve into all the gory details, go to https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Read everything there.  Read everything twice.  Enjoy your new knowledge.